# Can anyone help me with an Unrecognized device: Device descriptor request failed error on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have a Metrologic MS1690 Barcode scanner that I'm trying to use with Windows 8.1, I get a Unrecognized Device: Device descriptor request failed error in devices and printers. The scanner gets no power from the computer when it is plugged in because of this. It usually shows up as a usb keyboard in windows 8 and 7, but with 8.1 it does not and I can't find an answer anywhere. Please help! Or even if someone could tell me how to get a generic usb keyboard driver for this thing that may help as well. Thanks.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Were you ever able to resolve it?

Comment: there's a Windows 8 driver here, if you click on the software tab.  See if that works. https://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-US/Pages/Product.aspx?category=&cat=&pid=1690&rank=&=

Comment: @ps2goat, thanks for the tip. The device is made to work without any additional drivers (it is recognized as a USB HID device and works like a keyboard). The driver you see on that page is the USB-to-Serial emulator. In fact, I am using that driver now and it works well, but it's tangential to the issue. The scanner doesn't require it to operate and I'm seeing the issue with and without the driver installed.

Comment: __Update:__ I talked with reseller I bought the scanner from. He said the issue is not with Windows 8.1 but the USB chipset. It's not supplying the full 500mA that the scanner needs. I bought a [PCI-E USB card](http://smile.amazon.com/Rosewill-RC-228U2-PCI-Express-Controller-Profile/dp/B00CX7Q2QE/) and installed that. The scanner works a much higher percentage of the time now, but I have still run into the occasional disconnect (or failure to be recognized at start up).

Answer (score 1):

> The scanner gets no power from the computer when it is plugged in

Bit of a guess, but there was a change in Win8.1 that can affect HID devices like this.  Such devices are now suspended when no application or service is accessing it.  This can cause the device to misbehave if it depends on receiving timely power to operate correctly.

The workaround is to disable Enhanced Power Management for the device.  The instructions are pretty elaborately spelled-out in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usbcoreblog/archive/2013/11/08/help-after-installing-windows-8-1-my-usb-device-doesn-t-charge-or-it-disconnects-and-reconnects-frequently.aspx).  At break-neck speed: use Regedit.exe, locate the device in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ SYSTEM\ CurrentControlSet\ Enum\ USB key and set the EnhancedPowerManagementEnabled value to 0.

Comment: Good idea. I ran through the suggestions in the blog post. The device was showing up as being connected to a root USB hub. I had to add the __EnhancedPowerManagementEnabled__ DWORD to the Device Parameters (it wasn't already set as the blog suggests). No luck. I'm still getting intermittent disconnects. It was a good thought though.

Comment: I ordered in another USB cable for the scanner and tried that, no luck. I'm starting to think this is more hardware related than software. I am able to use the scanner without issue on a different Windows 8.1 box. However, I have problems running it from a laptop and a desktop (both running 8.1). The one that works is an older motherboard (X58 chipset). The two that don't work are newer. I don't know what this could mean, but it's something. I have a PCI-E USB card coming. I'm going to try that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The "solution" for me has been to add a PCI-E USB card, and use that for the scanner. I went with [this one from Rosewill](http://smile.amazon.com/Rosewill-RC-228U2-PCI-Express-Controller-Profile/dp/B00CX7Q2QE/) because it uses an NEC chipset which I have heard good things about.

After installing the provided drivers for the PCI-E card, the scanner seems to enumerate consistently (I have only been able to test it for a couple days so far).

According to the person I bought my scanner from, it's an issue with the USB chipset on the motherboard. Some are compatible and some aren't. If I had to do it over again, I would go with an RS232 cable and a power adapter instead of USB. I haven't tested that setup, but if your app needs serial data like mine does, it should be more reliable given that it's not dependent on the vagaries of integrated USB chipsets.